# Add Image in tabbar (.gif)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

> How to set an .gif in TabBar icons that'll animate?

Is it possible to add a **.gif** image to a tabBar icon. Is it possible to animate the picture?

Comment: see: https://dribbble.com/shots/1766396-Animated-Tab-Bar-Icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple words there are no api provided by apple for this but you can use third party library like [this](https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar)